# PHP 5.6 include/require ignores default stream context

Tags: php, ssl

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php:

> If "URL include wrappers" are enabled in PHP, you can specify the file to be included using a URL.

So you can include a file like this:

```
<?php
include 'https://localhost:1234/index.php';
?>
```

This works fine if you have a valid SSL certificate but if you're using a self signed certificate the peer certificate verification fails:

```
Warning: include(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in [...]
```

This wasn't a problem in older versions but PHP 5.6 enables peer verification by default (http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php).

Apparently you can set a default stream context using stream_context_set_default() where you can disable peer verification. So my code would look like this:

```
<?php
stream_context_set_default(
  array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    )
  )
);

include 'https://localhost:1234/index.php';
?>
```

But this doesn't work. The Include() function still attempts to verify the peer and fails. If I use file_get_contents(), fopen(), copy(), readfile(), or file() instead of include(), it works fine.

Now I'm not sure if this is a bug in PHP or if I'm missing something here. Same issue exists with require().

Any ideas?